# ¿Cómo recorrer un arreglo y conocer el posicionamiento de otro arreglo en PHP?

Tags: php, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo dos arreglos:

```
$array1 = array('n1' => 1, 'n2' => 2, 'n3' => 3);
$array2 = array('l1' => 'a', 'l2' => 'b', 'l3' => 'c');
```

Necesito recorrer el $array1 con foreach(){}

```
foreach($array1 as $keyArray1 => $valueArray1) {
    echo "La clave es $keyArray1 del $valueArray1 <br/>";
}
```

Pero a la vez necesito que se recorra el $array2, para que quede algo como un $array3 y poder imprimir en pantalla algo como:

```
echo "El valor del arreglo 1 es: $valueArray1 contra valor del arreglo 2 es $valueArray2";
```

No sé si el $array2 se recorra dentro del foreach(){}, lo intente pero me genera un producto cartesiano.
Lo que necesito es un $array3 formado por el $array1 y el $array2, utilice el método array_merge(); de php pero genera una concatenación uno despues de otro, no sé si hay una manrea de concatenar $array1 con $array2 pero por número de index o del $key.

¿Para que? Muy bien les dejo mi codigo en desarrollo (no es el mejor, una disculpa)

```
foreach ($_POST['fecha_convenio'] as $fechaConvenio) {
    $consecutivoPago = $numeroPago ++;
    $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBaseDatos -> prepare(
        "INSERT INTO bujic_payboard.montos_convenio (monto_convenio, fecha_convenio, consecutivo_pago, id_convenio) VALUES(:montoConvenio, :fechaConvenio, :consecutivoConvenio, :idConvenio)"
    );
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':montoConvenio', 500, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':fechaConvenio', $fechaConvenio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':consecutivoConvenio', $consecutivoPago, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':idConvenio', $lastInsertId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> execute();
}
```

En el foreach(){} se recorre una arreglo que tiene N cantidad de fechas o bueno una longitud, ahora bien funciona bien, pero requiero que en el paramentro de :montoConvenio que es un 500, eso es una cantidad de monto a pagar, sea dinamico desde otro array, los array de fecha convenio y monto convenio contienen la misma longitud.

**(Correción)**
De los dos arreglos necesito combinarlos o concatenarlos para que muestren con el forecha algo como:

```
$array1 = array('n1' => 1, 'n2' => 2, 'n3' => 3);
$array2 = array('l1' => 'a', 'l2' => 'b', 'l3' => 'c');
```

La primera oración es 1 con a
La segunda oración es 2 con b
...... hasta N oraciones

Para que así haga el INSERT nombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUE (1, a), por eso necesito que sean recorridos de esa manera.

Comment: Los valores de las claves del array1 y del array2 importan? Hay alguna relación entre ellas? Ambos arrays siempre tienen la misma longitud? Podria darse el caso que haya mas elementos en uno que en otro? Siempre llegan con las claves n(X) y l(X)? Podria darse el caso que las claves no se correspondan?

Comment: No, no importan solo coloque como referencia (Deja corrijo mi pregunta para mayor explicación). Siempre tienen la misma longitud, existe una validación (a.lenght == b.lenght). Si siempre mismas claves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi usando `array_values`:

```
$array1 = array('n1' => 1, 'n2' => 2, 'n3' => 3);
$array2 = array('l1' => 'a', 'l2' => 'b', 'l3' => 'c');

$array1=array_values($array1);
$array2=array_values($array2);

foreach ($array1 as $key => $val1){
    echo "{$val1} -> {$array2[$key]}, ";
    
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, me funciono exactamente como requería!

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción podría ser moviendo manualmente el apuntador en el segundo array con `next()`, mientras el primer array es recorrido en el `for`:

```php
<?php
// ...
foreach($array1 as $k1=>$v1) {
    echo $k1.'=>'.$v1.' -- '.key($array2).'=>'.current($array2).PHP_EOL;
    next($array2);
}
```

Resultado:

```
n1=>1 -- l1=>a
n2=>2 -- l2=>b
n3=>3 -- l3=>c
```